# Sum of product of binomials

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, poisson-process

While working on a combinatorics problem, I found that this result had to be true:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(a-b)^i(b-c)^{n-i}}{i!(n-i)!}=\frac{(a-c)^n}{n!}$$

for $a\geq b\geq c$, with $a,b,c\in\Bbb N$.

I tried expanding the binomial powers by using the binomial theorem and then trying to simplify everything, but I didn't succeed. The result reminds me somehow of the product of exponentials property:  $e^{a-b}e^{b-c}=e^{a-c}$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That *is* the  binomial theorem for $(x+y)^n$ with $x=a-b$ and $y=b-c$.

Comment: @MartinR You are totally right. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy....

$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(a-b)^i(b-c)^{n-i}}{i!(n-i)!}=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}(a-b)^i(b-c)^{n-i}=\frac{1}{n!}[(a-b)+(b-c)]^n=\frac{1}{n!}(a-c)^n$

EDIT:sorry I was still typing while the comment has been posted

Comment: Please use the term "binomial theorem" as Martin R. has done.